# AS3 Outline with glowfilter on partly transparent objects

Tags: actionscript-3, transparency, highlight

My problem is that I have some objects I want to create a highlight around. Currently I am using glowfilter to do this, it works perfectly fine most of the time. But when I have partly transparent objects I get a problem, for example, a window, since the glass in the window is transparent the glowfilter will be visible through it.

Is there a solution on how to make a nice outline, without having to worry about transparency?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you're getting, and a mock-up of what you'd like?  From your description, there isn't a problem: of course something transparent **in front** of other things will show those things behind it.

Comment: This is how it now looks without the glowfilter and with it: http://i.imgur.com/Ytui9x9.png 

But when it is highlighted I would want it to only have the blue border around it (as you see at the bottom of the movieclip), and not having the transparent part become all blue as well. So I am looking for a solution how I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

OK there are two answers, one is easy and non-coding based, and the other requires the first answer plus coding and is non-trivial.

Easy answer: Don't use transparency.  Flatten the source image, copy your part, and put a GlowFilter on it.  Simple, and probably the way you should go.

Not easy answer: What you're seeing is the normal behavior for Bitmap filters.  Instead, you will need to use a combination of at least two bitmaps, one **without any interior transparency** (same image part as in the Easy answer) that uses a GlowFilter with the `knockout` parameter set to true, and the other identical bitmap, without a filter, placed directly over it if you are intending to slide things between the device and the highlight.  Doing this is way beyond the scope of a simple question, and you should research it if the Easy Answer doesn't do it.